# php simplexml not read <sheet r:id="rId1"/>

Tags: php, simplexml

this is my code

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><workbook xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><sheet r:id="rId1"/></workbook>';
var_dump(simplexml_load_string($str));exit;
```

output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["sheet"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { } }
```

rId1 doesn't show,why?

Comment: It's not "gone", it just doesn't show when you use `var_dump`. Check the many many other questions about using SimpleXML with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Xpath to get that attribute.

```
<?php

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><workbook xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><sheet r:id="rId1"/></workbook>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$id = $xml->xpath('sheet/@r:id');
echo 'r:id= ' . $id[0]

?>
```

Output:

```
r:id = rId1
```